# Changing CSS in only one page (the contact us) in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

I made a website based on wordpress for a client. But the client is very strange, he want to have different design for the Contact Us page than other pages.

I made a CSS for Contact Us page, but if I add that CSS to the style.css in the theme directory, it will override the CSS (colors) for the rest of the pages too, but I want to change the CSS only for the Contact Us page.

The problem is that the pages we create in the Wordpress are not physical pages like in a static website, if that was the case i would add internal or inline CSS, but that doesn't work in my case.

Thank you all in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [wp_enqueue_style](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) can save you here.
The description for this wordpress function is, A safe way to add/enqueue a CSS style file to the wordpress generated page (in your case, its a wordpress generated page).

Use it as follows.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'addCustomCSS');
function addCustomCSS()
{
    if(is_page(your_page_title_goes_here))
    {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'link_to_your_custom_stylesheet_goes_here' );
    }
}
```

Comment: page title is the title you give when you're making the page (in your case the Contact Us) in the WordPress Admin Panel.

Comment: Yes, thank you , thank you, thank you, that worked for me. Can you please explain how did it work ?

Comment: I already described about the function wp_enqueue_style in the answer and also provided the link to that function in the wordpress codex,

also search other 3 functions at Wordpress codex,
1. is_page, 2. add_action, 3. wp_enqueue_scripts

This is the link to function reference at wordpress codex.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference

Answer (score 0):

Check if the page already has some different class for `body`

so if you have

```
<body class="page contact">
```

then you can use

```
body.contact h1{
display:none;
}
```

If you have a large amount of changes, it would be better you tweak the setting to include custom css for a page.